# How dismiss a viewController with storyboard from a push segue?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, storyboard, segue

I don't know why `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:`. I just want to do it.

I start with a

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"my_segue" sender:self];
```

But is I call the dismiss than nothing happens. I can create another segue, but it create a new view controller.

My question is: How dismiss the `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:`?

Answer (score 31):

Do you have a navigationBar in the viewController that's calling:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"my_segue" sender:self];
```

If so, you'll need to use:

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

to pop the view off the stack.  There's one segue call, but the framework seems to call:

```
presentViewController:animated:completion:
```

or:

```
pushViewController:animated:
```

as appropriate.

Ray

Comment: I was trying different combinations that centered around dismissViewController .... none of them worked.  Happy I found, and tried, your suggestion of 'popViewController' instead.  Not sure if this is true, but I can certainly see a possible relationship between a PUSH segue and the need for a reciprocal POP to get it off the stack.

Answer (score 2):

You could just call

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

from the view controller since the view controller was pushed by segue.

Answer (score 0):

`[my_segue_view_controller dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: YES]` ?

(not sure, but it works in my practice)

Comment: You should avoid using `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:`, as [the docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) say it is deprecated. `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:` should be used instead.

Answer (score 0):

`performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:` itself isn't dismissed, that's just the method that's called to initiate a named segue. What happens in the segue is of more interest.

You're right that you should call `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:`, and it should be called by the *presenting* view controller, which has previously called the *presented* view controller using `presentViewController:animated:completion:`. For more info, see [the UIViewcontroller docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code for **Swift 4** version

```
  self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
```